# Can't reach native ip 192.168.1.5 via Browser(Windows Server 2016 Datacenter)

Tags: windows, iis, windows-server-2016, localhost

On a Windows Server 2016 Datacenter

The default website can be accessed by local host and 127.0.0.1, 
but native IP(192.168.1.5) cannot be accessed.

What could cause this issue?

[iis bind](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iQpJ.jpg)
[localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rN7UU.png)
[127.0.0.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfOye.png)
[native ip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPmtl.png)
[network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YNxt.png)
[ping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVMlq.png)

Comment: `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` is kind of informative ...

Comment: A proxy, binding error, routing, firewall, AV, connection filter ... there are plenty of tings taht can go wrong. Did you do any troubleshooting? Ping, check for Proxy, telnet on port 80 ...